# How to repair winsxs folder without an external source?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 version 1909 (x64) is not able to install 2 windows updates patches, even after I manually downloaded them and tried to install manually:

1. KB4560960
2. KB4552931

With DISM command (DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth) I saw that there are some corruptions in winsxs folder.

The DISM log is full of sentences like these:

```
2020-06-18 20:51:07, Info                  CSI    0000013f Unable to load manifest for component [l:91 ml:140]'amd64_b1e65ebccde297c8e1ed5393f8845756_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15788.297_none_d3c8411750894c22'
2020-06-18 20:51:07, Info                  CSI    00000140 Manifest hash mismatch. Component: [l:91 ml:140]'amd64_b1e65ebccde297c8e1ed5393f8845756_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15788.297_none_d3c8411750894c22'
2020-06-18 20:51:07, Info                  CSI    00000141 Warning: Unable to repair manifest for component ([l:91 ml:140]'amd64_b1e65ebccde297c8e1ed5393f8845756_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15788.297_none_d3c8411750894c22') from backups directory with disposition (2). A backup file may not exist or may be corrupt. Falling back to WU.
2020-06-18 20:51:07, Info                  CSI    00000142 Manifest hash for component [l:91 ml:140]'amd64_b67be2085122225e9ec0811b07bff52a_b77a5c561934e089_4.0.15788.297_none_c0a206d5d437251e' does not match expected value.
```

What I can do? why windows is not able to download the missing files/components that are corrupted? It doesn't seem so complicated, Microsoft doesn't have out there an online repository with these files so that DISM can download the full files?

I don't have a Window10 disc or backup, how to proceed with the safest way without formatting?

Comment: you can [download the 1909 ISO easily](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557)

Comment: Thanks, Bu I don't find Windows 10 Enterpise 1909. I tried the windows 10, but it says source not find

Comment: get Enterprise ISO from MSDN subscription